# Numbers that are infinite on both ends of their decimal representation

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

Some time ago I learned about the p-adic numbers which, simply put, differ from the reals in that their decimal representations (base $p$) can have infinitely many digits to the left of the decimal point instead of to the right. I have been wondering whether the concept of a number system where both ends of a decimal representation may extend indefinitely makes sense and/or has any meaningful applications but I couldn't find any useful sources.

The usually stated flaw of such a number system (let's call it $\mathbb{M}$) is that it wouldn't have any well-defined absolute value, since the Ostrowski's theorem (1916) states that every non-trivial absolute value on the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$  is equivalent to either the usual real absolute value or a p-adic absolute value. Since we probably want $\mathbb{Q}$ to be the part of $\mathbb{M}$, we can from that conclude that $\mathbb{M}$ can also have no non-trivial absolute value other than that (otherwise it would also be an absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$), and both real and p-adic absolute values don't work on numbers that have two infinite ends.

But do we care? I mean, the juicy stuff like limits and continuity and connectedness come from a metric (or, more generally, from a topology) anyway, and these *may*, but *don't have to* be induced by an absolute value. Addition also seems well-defined, since formally, by commutativity and associativity (which we hope to hold true in $\mathbb{M}$), we can add any two numbers of the form $x.\!y$ and $u.\!v$ as

$$x.\!y+u.\!v=x.0+0.y+u.0+0.v=(x.0+u.0)+(0.y+0.v)$$

(here $.$ represents the decimal point; $x,u$ and $y,v$ are sequences of digits base $p$, possibly infinite on their respectful ends)
And from that, multiplication and probably subtraction can also be constructed.

In conclusion, even if the number system $\mathbb{M}$ is impossible, inconsistent or just plain useless, the reasons of that don't seem immediately obvious to me and I would greatly appreciate any clarification on the topic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And from that, multiplication and probably subtraction can also be constructed.

*Addition* certainly works, but *multiplication* is trickier than you may expect. The issue is that breaking into "left" and "right" pieces helps addition but runs into real issues with multiplication: because of the distributive law, we wind up needing to evaluate the product of a "left-infinite" number and a "right-infinite" number with each other.

To see that this is a problem, consider the simple example of $$...111.0\cdot 0.111...$$ (which arises when, for instance, we try to compute $...111.111...^2$). A reasonable first attempt at making sense of this is to break the second term into $0.1+0.01+0.001+...$ and then distribute, which yields $$...111.1 + ...111.11+...111.111+...,$$ which in turn yields ... what precisely? We wind up summing infinitely many $1$s in each place.

Indeed, this can be turned into an impossibility result: there is no way to make sense of multiplication of such "bi-infinite" numbers in a way that is continuous with respect to what seems the most natural topology, namely the topology generated by taking the $\mathbb{Z}$-fold product topology of the discrete topology on the set of digits $\{0,1,...,9\}$. This seems like a pretty fundamental limitation.

Comment: Thank you! Interestingly enough, your example seems to work fine if we consider addition base 2: $...111.1 + ...111.11 + ...111.111 + ... = ...111.01 + ...111.111 + ... = ...111.001 + ...$, the partial sum approaches $...111.000...$ pointwise (for any summation order!) which is kind of what we want since, taking intuition from the real numbers, we'd expect $0.111...$ to be another representation of $1.0$. But in base 3 the left part of the partial sum keeps switching between $...111.0$ and $...222.0$ which is most probably not good for any kind of convergence whatsoever.